# How do you make it so all youtube videos play the worst quality by default on ubuntu?

Tags: flash, youtube

The goal here is to use as little bandwidth as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like an Ubuntu related question. AFAIK it holds by your YouTube account settings. Anyway, I'll try to answer.

You must to log in on YouTube with your account. If you don't have one, you can create one. Then follow the instructions from the following image:

[image]

Comment: Nope; All that does is prevent HD video. It doesnt play the lowest quality format.

Comment: @Akiva That's all that you can do. Ubuntu has nothing to blame. The only thing that you can stop from Ubuntu is to stop playing flash videos at all.

Comment: I never said I was blaming Ubuntu for anything. It does house flash in its operating system however, and I am optimistic that a creative solution can be made here.

Comment: @Akiva Imagine  this: there is a solution in Ubuntu which can make to play youtube videos at 144p and the settings from your youtube account says 240p... Now, who will win?

Comment: With all due respect; if I can change it by hand, then I can change via a programming pipe of some sort. In this case, it is not like I am asking for a format that does not yet exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Firefox plugin for doing this. I haven't used it myself, and it doesn't appear to support 144p, but it might be worth a try.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-quality-manager/